# Matlab - save calculated variable with 5 decimal cases

Tags: matlab, format, size

I want to use a calculated variable which result has 5 decimal cases, but Matlab saves it with only 4. But I need it to have 5 decimal cases to use it in the rest of the code.

Hence: I do NOT want to display this variable to the user.

Example:
L=10;
N=1600;

fs=L/N;

Matlab stores "fs" as "0.0063" instead of "0.00625", and I need it to be "0.00625".

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: MATLAB does store it with more decimal places by default, it just doesn't show them. If you want to show them, try the command `format long`, which lets you see up to 15 decimal places. So you can safely continue calculating with your `fs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in function `digits(n)` where n is the precision parameter.

```
digits(5)
fs=vpa(L/N)

fs=0.00625
```